# Python PIL Pillow - bad transparency mask when converting PNG to JPG

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I want to convert and resize png image file into jpg.

What I want to achieve are:
(1)Import PNG files,
(2)Get the file name and extension,
(3)Resize the images to be 1000x1000 (proportional resize method, not stretching to the frame),
(4)Creating BG 1000x1000,
(5)Place images in the middle of canvas,
(6)Save it into JPG

This script is fully functioned for JPG or another format (like eps), but always throw an error **"bad transparency mask"** for PNG (not always, but chance its like 90% will error). I think its related to alpha channel or something that I am not understand enough.

Here my code:

```py
        #Open an Image
        dirLoadOpenFile = parentFolder + '_images\\before2\\'
        #img = Image.open(dirLoadOpenFile + importFile[i])
        try:
            img = Image.open(dirLoadOpenFile + importFile[i])
        except (FileNotFoundError): #catch an error if file doesnt exist
            errorExport = errorExport + 1
            break
            
        checkExt = importFile[i]
        checkExt = checkExt[-3:]
        
        if checkExt == "png":
            img.convert('RGBA')
            img.putalpha(255)
        else:
            img.convert('RGB')
            
        #Resizing image
        hasilResize = resize_image(img, 1000, 1000, False)

        #Creating white background 1000x1000
        white = (255, 255, 255, 255)
        background = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 1000), white)

        #Placing image on the middle (center) of canvas
        img_w, img_h = hasilResize.size
        bg_w, bg_h = background.size
        offsetMiddle = ((bg_w - img_w) // 2, (bg_h - img_h) // 2)
        
        if checkExt == "png":
            background.paste(hasilResize, offsetMiddle, mask=hasilResize)
        else:
            background.paste(hasilResize, offsetMiddle)
            
        #Saving an images
        dirLoadSaveFile = parentFolder + "_images\\after2\\"
        background.save(dirLoadSaveFile + saveFile[i], quality=100, optimize=True, progressive=True)
```

Its really confusing though. Could some assist me, please?
Sample:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfJ85.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qGJa.png

Comment: Can you please describe in detail, what you actually want to achieve? Only given the examples, it's not clear at all. From the code: You load JPG? or PNG? images, put some all opaque alpha channel for the PNGs (i.e. no transparency here), paste the image on some solid white background with `mode='RGB'` (i.e. no transparency here either), and save that as PNG? or JPG? Where and how do you expect to get some transparency?

Comment: @HansHirse I dont want any transparency since I want to export in JPG files. 

What I want to achieve are: (1)Import PNG files, (2)Get the file name and extension, (3)Resize the images to be 1000x1000 (proportional resize method, not streching to the frame) (4)Creating BG 1000x1000, (5)Place images in the middle of canvas, (6)Save it into JPG

Comment: This script is fully functioned for JPG or another format (like eps), but always throw an error for PNG (not always, but chance its like 90% will error). I think its related to alpha channel or something that I am not understand enough.

Comment: What happens, if you remove all that specific PNG stuff? Just `img.convert('RGB')` and `background.paste(hasilResize, offsetMiddle)` for all images, even PNG? Please provide a [mre] including an image, for which the code fails.

Comment: It will fail too. Thats the first thing I do and already try it. After get an error on first try, my next action are: (1)try to convert first to ```RGBA``` and (2)I found similar problem on stackoverflow can be solve by adding mask from its resize. I am running this code on office workspace, later any SS will be provide. Meanwhile, could you please suggest me another way?